# Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] (even though I have given the callback function)

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, express-router

I am creating a simple blog backend (API).

I tried creating a router and now I have an issue that I don't understand how to debug.

This is the router.

```
const express = require('express');
const Article = require('../models/Article')
let router = express.Router();
const app = require('../app');


router.get('/:articleId', (req,res) => {
    Post.findOne({_id : req.params.articleId})
    .then(doc => {
        if(!doc) res.send('No such post in DB')
        res.send(doc).sendStatus(200)
    })
    .catch(err => res.send({'error' : `you got some error - ${err}`}).sendStatus(400))
})

router.post('/', app.auth, async (req,res)=>{
    if(req.auth) {
        const doc = await User.findOne({uname : req.user});
        const article = {
            authorId : doc._id,
            article : {
                title : req.body.title,
                content : req.body.article
            },
            tags : req.body.tags
        }
        const newArticle = new Article(article)
        const savedArticle = await newArticle.save()
        res.send(savedArticle)
    }
    else {
        res.redirect('./login')
    }
    //if(localStorage.token) verify(token) get the userId and post the article with authorId = userId
    //if (not verified) redirect to the login page
    //get to know the jwt tokens
})

module.exports = { router };
```

This is the index file `app.js`. Just the part with the issue. And there is `auth` which I am exporting and is working fine within the `app.js`.

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const env = require('dotenv').config();
const article = require('./routes/article')

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended : true}));

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology : true
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully connected to the database");    
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Could not connect to the database. Exiting now...', err);
    process.exit();
})

app.use("/article", article)
module.exports = {auth}

app.listen(port, ()=>{console.log(`Server running at port ${port}`)});
```

And this is the Model for Article

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Article = new mongoose.Schema({
    authorId : {
        type : String,
        required :true,
        default : "anonymous"
    },
    article : {
        title : {
            type : String,
            required : true
        },
        content : {
            type : [String],
            required : true
        },
        imgFiles : [String]
    },
    like : Number,
    starred : Number,
    date : {
        type : Date,
        required : true,
        default : Date.now()
    },
    tags : [String]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Article', Article)
```

And this is the error
[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is being caused because you are importing *article.js* into *app.js* and then importing the *app.js* into *article.js* creating a circular dependency. Remove that `module.exports = {auth}` from *app.js*. Note that you haven't even declared the auth function. You you should create the *auth* function in another file and import it into article.js.

Also this line `module.exports = { router };` should just be `module.exports = router;`

*auth.js*

```
function auth(req, res, next) {
  // IMplementation
}
module.exports = auth
```

*article.js*

```
const express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();
const auth = require('./auth');


router.get('/:articleId', (req,res) => {
    res.send('article')
})

router.post('/', auth, async (req,res)=>{
    res.send('response')
})

module.exports = router;
```

*app.js*

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const article = require('./article')

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended : true}));

app.use("/article", article)

app.listen(3000, ()=>{console.log(`Server running at port 3000`)});
```

Comment: Yeah, I also once thought that was the issue but it isn't. I had moved that to another `config` file and importing it from there in both the files. But then this `TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object` is raised. And every time I try to make some changes that I think, might solve the issue to understand where the issue is coming from, another issue is raised. Unless I remove the `article.js` file from  `app.js`, there  is always an error. I commented out the article.post request but then the error of `Router.use()` is raised. Please try to find another problem

Answer (score 0):

I was making a simple mistake.

I was doing this.

```
module.exports = { router }
```

instead of

```
module.exports = router
```

Comment: @D_M has already said this in his answer. Why are you writing it again here?

Comment: That's why I have upvoted his answer but he was also talking about inter-dependency. Wanted to exclude that, because it might come up as a bug in your API later but is not syntactically wrong.

Answer (score -1):

for me I was importing my middleware as

```
const { default: fetchuser } = require("../middleware/fetchuser");
```

which I need to import like

```
const fetchuser = require("../middleware/fetchuser");
```

and I was exporting as

```
module.exports = { router }
```

instead of

```
module.exports = router;
```

**conclusion: you should Import and export both correctly**

Comment: Which is what the OP said two years ago.